# Highlight the data within Excel wrapped cell being searched once found

Tags: python, excel, vba

Is there a way to highlight the word or data being searched in Excel if the data is within the wrapped cell? I am using the Ctrl + F to find the data, though it will direct me to the wrapped cell, I still have to read all the data in there.

Hope you can give me an advice to this issue. Thank you in advance.